# How to provide window width to all React components that need it inside my app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, react-hooks

So I've got this hook to return the `windowWidth` for my App components. I'll call this **Option #1**.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function useWindowWidth() {

  const [windowWidth,setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {

    function handleResize() {
      setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowWidth;
}

export default useWindowWidth;
```

And right now I'm basically using it on every component that depends on the window width to render, like:

```
function Component(props) {
  const windowWidth = useWindowWidth();
  return(
    // RETURN SOMETHING BASED ON WINDOW WIDTH
  );
}
```

And since the hook has an event listener for the `resize` events, the component stays responsive even after window resizes.

But I'm worried that I'm attaching a new listener for every component that uses that hook and it might slow things down at some point. And I've though of other approach:

**Option #2**

I use the `useWindowWidth()` hook only one time, inside a top level component like `<App/>` and I'll provide the `windowWidth` value down the chain via context.

Like:

```
function App() {
  const windowWidth = useWindowWidth();
  return(
    <WindowWidthContext.Provider value={windowWidth}>
      <Rest_of_the_app/>
    </WindowWidthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

And then, every component that needs it could get it via:

```
function Component() {
  const windowWidth = useContext(WindowWidthContext);
  return(
    // SOMETHING BASED ON WINDOW WIDTH
  );
}
```

**QUESTION**

Am I right in being bothered by that fact that I'm setting up multiple `resize` listeners with **Option #1** ? Is **Option #2** a good way to optmize that flow?

Comment: The custom hook is perfectly fine to use, you remove the listener when component unmounts You may want to debounce when resizing to prevent many updates from firing.

Comment: @HMR thanks! I've got a debounced version that I use. But isn't it a problem that I'm adding and removing event listeners to the `window` object many times? I don't know, this could be a really cheap operation to make, but it kind of bothers me that I'm setting up multiple listeners when 1 would be enough. What do you think?

Comment: You would have better performance with context or using a state manager like redux to store the width value but even if you have hundreds of components doing that the debounce would probably be a better performance boost. You could make useWindowWidth in such a way that it gets its width from a singleton object.

Comment: What you ended up doing? I'm facing the same use case and I don't really get why would you prefer attaching multiple listeners to the global object over Context

Comment: I guess performance-wise it wouldn't matter for 99% of the use cases. Unless you are doing something too extreme, both should work just the same. But today I guess I would choose setting just one listener and providing it down the tree either using context or redux. But it's been a while since I've used this kind of hook. I was using for responsiveness but today a basically only use CSS media queries and they'll make your life much easier if you are doing SSR.

Answer (score 1):

If your window with is used by so many components as you mentioned, you must prefer using `context`. As it reads below:

> Context is for global scope of application.

So, `#2` is perfect choice here per react.

First approach `#1` might be good for components in same hierarchy but only up-to 2-3 levels.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if adding and removing event listeners is a more expensive operation than setting and deleting map keys but maybe the following would optimize it:

```
const changeTracker = (debounceTime => {
  const listeners = new Map();
  const add = fn => {
    listeners.set(fn, fn);
    return () => listeners.delete(fn);
  };
  let debounceTimeout;
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    clearTimeout(debounceTimeout);
    debounceTimeout = setTimeout(
      () => {
        const width=window.innerWidth;
        listeners.forEach(l => l(width))
      },
      debounceTime
    );
  });
  return add;
})(200);
function useWindowWidth() {
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(
    () => window.innerWidth
  );
  useEffect(
    () =>//changeTracker returns a remove function
      changeTracker((width) =>
        setWindowWidth(width)
      ),
    []
  );
  return windowWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As HMR said in an above thread, my solution was to use redux to hold the width value. With this strategy you only need one listener and you can restrict how often you update with whatever tool you like. You could check if the width value is within the range of a new breakpoint and only update redux when that is true. This only works if your components dont need a steady stream of the window width, in that case just debounce.

Comment: Hey there. In Stackoverflow it's considered "best practise" to mark an answer as your solution, in stead of just creating a new answer saying which answer helped you out.

For future searchers it's also nice to have your solution in the question itself.